# configchanges compile error

Tags: android, compilation, intellij-idea, android-manifest, admob

I've had this problem and I can't find a solution. I'm using Intellij. I have the SDK set to Android 4.03, target=android-13, android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15", and still I get a compile error

... error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize').

It highlights just the 'screenSize|smallestScreenSize' part, but without those two the AdMob ads don't work.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it! Because I had originally set it for a lower API, in the dependencies it was still set to Android 2.0.3, despite saying that the SDK was 4.0.3.